# i was trying to add data in room db but not able to add more than 50 rows

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-room, android-room-relation

I was trying to add some data in room database android. but while adding there is only 50 rows are visible or entered in db. there is no more data is able to add in db. I also check my logs but there is no error or exception. I print each data in the log it is visible in the log but not available in db. there are no limits while creating room db I have put. please help me if anyone know what went wrong

Comment: If you want assistance with your issue then you need to provide the code that you are using when inserting the rows and also the process (code and/or technique) that you are using to establish that the rows are not available, as the fault could be within that process.  As you are using room, then you should also include the relevant class(es) annotated with `@Entity` and additionally the relevant functions (Dao's) annotated with `@Insert` and `@Query`.

Answer (score 6):

You may have already solved this but in case not, the entries in your table are displayed in pages, and 50 is the maximum number of entries displayed per page. If you look at the bottom right hand corner of the database inspector window, you'll see controls for advancing onto the next page where you should see your additional entries past 50.